# Showing the existence of a function $M \rightarrow L.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, modules, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. For $R-$modules $L,M,N$ show that the following conditions are equivalent.(all functions are $R-$ module homomorphisms.)

a- $M \cong_{R} L \oplus N.$

b- There exists a left-split short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow{L} \rightarrow{M} \rightarrow{N} \rightarrow{0.}$

**Here is my trial:**

$a \implies b.$

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. And let $L,M,N$ be $R-$modules.

Assume that $M \cong_{R} L \oplus N.$ We want to show that there exists a left-split short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow{L} \rightarrow{M} \rightarrow{N} \rightarrow{0.}$$ i.e., $\exists$ a retraction $r: M \rightarrow{L}$ s.t.$$r \circ i = id_L \quad (1)$$ Where $i: L \rightarrow M $ and it is injective. So we need to find the functions $r,i$ that satisfies $(1)$ above.

So, since $M \cong_R L \oplus N,$ we can say that we have $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow L \oplus N  \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0,$ with $i:  L \rightarrow L \oplus N$ the embedding $i(l) = (l,0)$ and  $p:  L \oplus N \rightarrow N$ the projection $p(l,n) = n.$

If we define $r:  L \oplus N  \rightarrow N $ with $r(l,n) = l$ then we have $(r\circ i) (l) = r((l,0)) = l$ as required.

Now, we want to verify that $r$ is an $R-$module homomorphism:

1- $r((l_{1},n_{1}) + (l_{2}, n_{2})) = r((l_{1} + l_{2}, n_{1} + n_{2})) = l_{1} + l_{2} = r((l_{1}, n_{1})) + r((l_{2},n_{2}))$ where the first equality is by definition of addition in direct sum.

2- Let $r' \in R$ and let $m \in M,$ then $r(r'm) = $ **but then I do not know how to complete. could anyone help me in this step please? also, is my solution correct?**

**Also I do not know how to prove the reverse direction, could anyone help me in this please?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $r' \in R$ and $(l,n) \in L \oplus N$, $$r(r'(l,n)) = r((r'l,r'n)) = r'l = r'r((l,n)),$$ and this shows that $r(r'm) = r'r(m)$ for every $r' \in R$ and $m \in L \oplus N$. Now, for $b \!\implies\! a$, tag the left-split short exact sequence $0 \to L \to M \to N \to 0$ as $$0 \longrightarrow L \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} M \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} N \longrightarrow 0$$ and let $r : M \to L$ be the $R$-module homomorphism such that $r \circ i = \operatorname{id}_L$. Show that the induced homomorphism $(r,p) : M \to L \oplus N$ given by $(r,p)(m) := (r(m),p(m))$ is an isomorphism using the fact that $r$ and $p$ are surjective (why?) and that $\ker r \cap \operatorname{im} i = 0$.

Comment: So do I have to prove that dealing with direct sum is the same as dealing with the direct produc in case of finite number of modules?

Comment: @hard Yes, the direct sum of a finite number of modules coincides with their direct product. If you are stuck with the injectivity of $(r,p)$, note that $\operatorname{im} i = \ker p$.

Comment: Could you please tell me why $\operatorname{ker} r \cap \operatorname{im} i = 0$?

Comment: That follows from the fact that $r \circ i = \operatorname{id}_L$. If you take $x \in \ker r \cap \operatorname{im} i$, then $r(x)=0$, but since $x \in \operatorname{im} i$, it follows that...

Comment: I do not know why $r$ and $p$ are both surjective ..... could you please explain that?

Comment: Sure, $r$ is surjective since for any $l \in L$ we have $l = r(i(l))$, and $p$ is surjective since $\operatorname{im}p = \ker(N \to 0)$.

Comment: oh by the properties of SESs